# Free alternatives to ChemDraw

Tags: software

My school doesn't offer me a ChemDraw license and I need to be able to draw quite complex chemical structures (e.g. porphyrins). This is why I am interested in some good free alternatives to ChemDraw. So far I have only been able to find programs that are a pain to use and it is very hard for me to draw anything more complex.